# WPF Ribbon in Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview?

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I am keen to create a new program that uses WPF Ribbon with C#. I am using Windows 8 and the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview (Professional edition), however when I tried to install the toolkit from Microsoft it didn't do anything. I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't do anything"? Installer never showed any UI? Installer ran but nothing new appeared in the Toolbox?

Comment: It installed OK, however the WPF Ribbon projects don't appear in VS11 and there aren't any controls in the toolbox either.

Comment: Given this is a question about a beta application (localized imho), I think your best bet is to post something on MS's forums about the preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ribbon is supported out of the box in .NET 4.5.  Add a reference to `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon` and change the xaml of your page to use a `<RibbonWindow>` instead of a `<Window>`. Put a `<Ribbon>` in your page and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! The problem arose because originally it didn't have any support but obviously this is fixed by being includes by default.